# Pass multiple data with redirect()->route() in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, redirect, parameters, routes

I have this route in web.php:

```
Route::get('student/evaluation/{evaluation}', [EvaluationController::class, 'getEvaluationQuestions'])->middleware('auth')->name('student.questionsevaluation');
```

And in my controller I have this condition, where $questionWasCompleted is boolean

```
if($questionWasCompleted){

return redirect()->route('student.questionsevaluation', $evaluation)->with('message', 'Question answered.');
            
}
```

How can I pass the $questionWasCompleted parameter in this redirect()->route() ?

Comment: Sorry, is there any way to be able to pass the parameter with compact() method?

Comment: In this case, nope

Comment: How can I get the value of $questionWasAnswered to know if it's true or false in the view file?

Comment: ```{{ $questionWasAnswered }}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a second `with()` method in your controller like this:

```
return redirect()->route('student.questionsevaluation', $evaluation)
->with('message', 'Question answered.')
->with('question', $questionWasCompleted);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the both parameters in the same `with()` method like this:

```
return redirect()->route('student.questionsevaluation', $evaluation)
->with(['message' => 'Question answered.',
        'question' => $questionWasCompleted]);
```